# Android GoogleMaps v1 LocationManager working odd on 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an application that used to locate a user's location with this code

```
public static Location getCurrentLocation(Context context) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);
    Location location;
    if (provider == null) {
        location = new Location("gps");
        location.setLatitude(U.LATITUDE);
        location.setLongitude(U.LONGITUDE);
    } else {
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location == null) {
            location = new Location("gps");
            location.setLatitude(U.LATITUDE);
            location.setLongitude(U.LONGITUDE);
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

This code appears to only be returning the behavior when provider is null or location is null. My guess is that something changed in this code.

```
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);
```

Comment: I will try and find an error but so far I haven't found one. However, I have noticed that when I turn off GPS services it goes to a place close to my location. When I turn the GPS back on it goes to my default GPS location in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I have some code very similar to yours and it stopped working on my device after the upgrade to Android 4.4 (i.e. getBestProvider returned null which it never did before).

I discovered the reason when I saw that another App displayed that the NetworkProvider wasn't available (although I had perfect connection to both wifi and 3G) and it could not get a GPS signal (obviously, because I was indoors). Then I toggled Android's location quick setting and a dialog popped up, asking me to agree to the new location management of Android 4.4 (see https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3467281). Afterwards, my code worked as before.